# Poor transfer speed over WiFi direct for HDR-AZ1. What can be done?

Tags: wifi, sony, sony-camera-api

We are developing an Android app that communicate with a Sony HDR-AZ1 through a WiFi direct connection. Everything works fine, but we are seeing extremely varying transfer speeds when downloading content from the camera to the Android device.

When transferring content, the speed varies between 50 Kbps and 700 Kbps, from the tests we've made so far, but mostly we end up in the lower end. I'm not sure if this is a problem with our implementation, or if it is a known issue with the camera?

Reading up on Wifi direct, we should be able to expect normal Wifi speeds i.e. far higher than what we see in our tests?

Is there some known tip on something we can do in our implementation to boost speed? Or is there another Sony camera to use instead, that has a better Wifi adapter? I'm looking at the X1000V and the AS200V, but I don't know if it would make a difference?

We are running the latest Android version on a Nexus 5, as well as the most recent firmware on the camera.

Comment: Might be your wireless router Throttling the wifi bandwidth?  Maybe check wifi router settings.

Comment: @SeanCarroll Since it is WiFi Direct, it is a peer-to-peer connection between the two devices, so there is no router involved in the connection.

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson did you ever figure out the solution to this? I'm currently looking to implement Sony's Camera API for my Android application, but I need to be connected to the internet simultaneously while connected to the camera. Wi-Fi direct seems to be the only way to do that, but seeing your comment worries me that the transfer speeds would be too slow over Wi-Fi direct for whatever reason.

Comment: @SirNeuman Unfortunately no. We've put that project on hold, and I haven't been looking into it any further.

Answer (score 0):

We don't publish the speeds of the WiFi connectivity on our cameras and other than running the latest FW there is nothing to improve the connection speed unfortunately.

Comment: What we've experienced is that the wifi-connection to the camera appear to be very sensitive to other wifi-connections in the vicinity. When run in an environment without other wifi-networks, we average around 1 Mbit. I realize that you dont publish speeds, but does that sound like what you should expect?